# Время в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйтe. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему без загрузки ядра `wp-load.php` время 07:45, а с загрузкой 04:45? Как сделать, чтобы время было одинаковое в обоих случаях?

```
<?php

echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', 1615956333) . '<br>';
// Дата: 17/03/2021 07:45:33

require_once ('./wp-load.php');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', 1615956333);
// Дата:17/03/2021 04:45:33

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WordPress надо пользоваться функцией [current_time](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_time)().

```
<?php
echo date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s' ) . "\n"; // Текущее время.

require_once 'C:\laragon\www\test\wp-load.php';

echo date( 'd/m/Y H:i:s' ) . "\n"; // UTC.

echo current_time( 'd/m/Y H:i:s' ); // Текущее время.
```

На то есть много причин, особенно после изменений в компоненте Date/Time в WordPress 5.3: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/date-time-improvements-wp-5-3/

Answer (score 1):

В админке Настройки - Общие - Часовой пояс. Внесите нужный (или UTC +3), и будет у Вас одинаковое время.

Comment: добрый день. Выбирал - то же самое. В админке всё ОК, а если напрямую в скрипте, то не ОК. Пришлось выставить `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`